# MySQL CREATE TABLE statement from diagram

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship

Provide a set of MySQL specific CREATE TABLE statements that implement tables for the following entities including the FK relationships implied by the associations. Note that each GamePlayed is associated with a Player and Game.

[image: Diagram here]

What will be the primary key in each table? and what does 0..N means in this diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use generated id (i.e. auto increment field) in game and player tables as primary key. Use these 2 fields together as a primary key in gameplayed table.
2. 0..n means that for each record in the parent table you can have 0 or unlimited number of corresponding record in the child table.